# Python/Heroku Spotify .cache archive problem

Tags: python, heroku, spotify

I'm developing a Chrome Extension that convert YouTube music to a Spotify item.

When I click the "addspotify" button, it shows my playlists to select which I'll add the music:
[image]

But it only works at my localhost, when I test in my Heroku deploy it shows this log:
[image]

This is the .cache that the Spotify API creates:
[image]

Comment: If you are going to provide photos please make sure to embed them using the image button rather than linking externally.

Comment: Where does `.cache` come from? Does it get written at runtime?

Comment: the `.cache`  file comes from the startup of my Spotify class, when i first call it opens a tab requesting authorization, after accept it, a `.cache` is created with a access token